# Copy radio button values with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am trying to copy data from one area to another using javascript . Everything was working fine for me but I am not able to copy the `radio button` values . I have used the folllowing to copy:

`gender = form.gender.checked;`

And to copy:

`form.gender.checked = form.billing_gender.value;`

But it is showing nothing . Please help.

This is my HTML code -

```
<label for="sname" ><span class="styleReq">*</span>Gender:</label> 
<input type="radio" id="gndr" name="billing_gender" 
    value="male" />&nbsp;&nbsp;MALE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="radio" id="gndr2" name="billing_gender" 
    value="female" />&nbsp;&nbsp;FEMALE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
```

Comment: Provide the code for your radio button.

Comment: `<label for="sname" ><span class="styleReq">*</span> Gender:</label> 
<input type="radio" id="gndr" name="billing_gender" value="male"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;MALE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="radio" id="gndr2" name="billing_gender" value="female" />&nbsp;&nbsp;FEMALE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="cleaner_h10"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var gender;
    if(form.billing_gender[0].checked == true) {
        gender = document.billing_gender.name[0].value;
    }
    else if(form.billing_gender[1].checked == true) {
        gender = document.billing_gender.name[1].value;
    }
```

Or you may use loop. Have your input button use this function:

```
function get_value() {
    for (var i=0; i < document.form.billing_gender.length; i++)
    {
        if (document.form.billing_gender[i].checked == true)
        {
        var gender = document.form.billing_gender[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```